# Shopify create radio buttons options for each product

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, shopify

I am developing on Shopify and I am trying to create the ability for the customer to build a computer. But, I cant find way to do this. I want to make it look similar to www.cyberpowerpc.com/system/CyberPower_Z77_Configurator/
If I do it with JavaScript, how do i connect to the shopping card for the final price?
I also have read the Shopify API, but nothing helpful. Any tips please!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the final price is the sum of the components, you could create a configurator-tool using Javascript. Shopify has a small [AJAX API](http://wiki.shopify.com/Ajax_API) library available, which can add products to the cart, look for product details etc.